# laravel & Blade Dynamically load column names from table

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to populate my user profile forms and since the database table has a lot of columns I'm trying to see if it's possible to load them automatically.

I sort of have it working. But at the moment it prints out a list of numbers (the table column ID I assume), rather than the names of the columns.

What am I missing?

This is the blade file:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')
    <h1>User Profile Data</h1>

        @foreach ($columns as $column => $name)
            {{ $column }}

        @endforeach

            @foreach ($profile as $person)
                @foreach ($person as $name)
                    {{ $name }}<br>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach

@stop
```

This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserEntryController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
       $columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('users');
       $profile = DB::table('users')->where('ID', '682')->get();
       return view('UserEntry', compact('profile', 'columns'));
   }
}
```

Comment: try to print `{{ $name }}` instead of `{{ $collumn }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I sort of have it working. But at the moment it prints out a list of
>   numbers (the table column ID I assume), rather than the names of the
>   columns.

No, you are not watching "table column ID" rather the numbers are the keys of `$columns` array. See clearly that you only fetched column names not the column(id)'s values in your controller.

Only the reason you are printing keys instead of values(column names in this case) of `$columns` in your view. print `$name` only

```
@foreach ($columns as $column => $name)
   {{ $name }}
@endforeach
```